# Infimum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find supremum and infimum for a function
$ (x-2y)/(1+4x^2+9y^2)$ in $R^2$
The function has a local maximum at $(x,y)=(3/10,-4/15)$ and minimum $(-3/10,4/15)$ and I have a problem how to prove that it is a global maximum/minimum. How to prove that in infinity the function does not have lower/higher values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x,y)=(r \cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, you can bound the absolute value of your function by

$$|f(x,y)|\leq \frac r {1+4r^2}|\cos\theta-2\sin\theta|\leq 3\frac r {1+4r^2}.$$

Therefore $f$ converges to $0$ at infinity, so if your local extrema are of opposite signs, they are necessarily global extrema.